# Cannot create Google BigQuery Materialized View when aggregating a value coming from a JSON type value

Tags: google-bigquery, materialized-views

I have Firestore database with an installed Google BigQuery extension, so all our data ends up in Google's BigQuery.

the structure of our 'raw_changelog' table looks like this.

[image]

my queation is related to the `data` column (which is of type JSON) and the fact I cannot seem to build a Materialized View (MV) on top it.

I'd like to create the following MV;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `XXX.XXX.v_data`
  PARTITION BY DATE(`published_at`)
  CLUSTER BY `event_id`
  OPTIONS (
    enable_refresh=true,
    refresh_interval_minutes=1
  )
  AS
  SELECT  
    `published_at`,
    `event_id`,
    ARRAY_AGG(`tags_unnest`.`name` IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`
  FROM `XXX.XXX.XXX_raw_latest` AS `o`
  LEFT JOIN UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(`data`.`tags`)) AS `tags_unnest`
  WHERE 
    DATE(`o`.`published_at`) > '2021-01-01'
  GROUP BY
  `published_at`,
  `event_id`
```

However I'm getting the following error;

[image]

I found at that the error is related to line;

```
ARRAY_AGG(`tags_unnest`.`name` IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`
```

I verified that `tags_unnest` is of type object (coming from the JSON `data` field) and it seems the issue comess from the fact `tags_unnest` is an object I guess.

if I replace the above line with;

```
ARRAY_AGG('aa' IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`
```

OR

```
ARRAY_AGG(`published_at` IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`
```

then it works fine and I can go ahead create the MV.

Perhaps also good to note; in the source table, if I change the type of the `data` field to 'STRING' then my original create-MV-query also runs without any issues..

Can anyone tell me why I cannot create the MV and possibly also a way around my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for the Materialized View: Please replace the `LEFT JOIN` by a `,`

For a  Materialized View (MV) there is a limit amount of calculations allowed.
The [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create?hl=en#query_limitations) says that Left/right/full outer joins are not allowed in MV and e.g. **only one** `GROUP BY` clause operation is allowed.

Your query contains the following 4 task operations:

- `unnest`-ing an json array, containing an object
- a `left join`
- an object selection (`.name`or `.x`) and
- an `array_agg`.

If you use one less operation, it should work. Replace the `left join` by a `,`

Lets build a dummy table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  Test.ajson AS
SELECT
  1 published_at, 1 event_id, json ' {"a":[1],"tags":[{"x":1}]}  ' AS DATA, [1,2] arr
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2,  json ' {"a":[2],"tags":[{"x":2},{"x":20}]}  ',  []
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 1,  json ' {"tags":[{"x":10}]}  ',   []
UNION ALL SELECT 5,5,json "{}", []
```

Now build the MV:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `Test.ajsonview` as
 SELECT 
    published_at, 
    event_id,
 ARRAY_AGG(`tags_unnest`.`x` IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`,
# ARRAY_AGG(`tags_unnest` IGNORE NULLS) AS testing
FROM Test.ajson 
, # works
#left join # throws error: Incremental materialized view query contains unsupported feature.
UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(`data`.`tags`)) tags_unnest
WHERE published_at>0
group by 1,2
```

Note that the `ARRAY_AGG` without the `.x`:

```
 ARRAY_AGG(`tags_unnest` IGNORE NULLS) AS testing
```

is working in combination with `LEFT JOIN`.

The `Tags` column can be empty, therefore the functionality of `LEFT JOIN` is needed and `,` does not work directly. There is dirty workaround for that: Duplicate the table with `unnest([1,2]) as temp01`. In case for `temp01=1` we unnest the `tags`. For `temp01=2` a dummy json is added to the dataset `[json '{"x":-9877}']`. In the `array_agg` only the `temp01=1` tags are keept.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW `Test.ajsonview` as
 SELECT 
    published_at, 
    event_id,
 ARRAY_AGG(if(temp01=1,`tags_unnest`.`x`,null) IGNORE NULLS) AS `tags`,
FROM Test.ajson,
  unnest([1,2]) as temp01, 
  UNNEST(if(1=temp01,JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(`data`.`tags`),[json '{"x":-9877}'])) tags_unnest
WHERE published_at>0
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel for your comment! I was unaware of the 3-task limitation. the comma implies an inner join (if I'm not mistaken), not every row in our data set has tags, that's why the original query uses a left join. 

do you have any additional recommendations, aside from replacing the left with an inner join, that could help my case?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Samuel' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77298414/4929221), the following query was composed based on cleanliness, readability, functionally. this solved our use-case

Thanks Samuel for your insights!

```
SELECT
    o.document_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(tags_unnest.name IGNORE NULLS) AS tags
FROM
    `Test.ajson` AS o,
    UNNEST(IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(data.tags)) > 0, JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(data.tags), [JSON '{}'])) AS tags_unnest
WHERE
    DATE(o.published_at) > '2023-10-10'
GROUP BY
    o.document_id;
```